# Why $P(|X -\mu|\geqslant r)=P(|X -\mu|^2\geqslant r^2)$?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I understand that the basic idea behind the proof is:

take $Y = |X-\mu|$

because $|X-\mu|^2 = (X-\mu)^2 $

then you can prove that $P(Y^2 \geqslant r^2) \leqslant \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{r^2})$ through Markov's.

What I just can't seem to grasp is why $P(|X -\mu|\geqslant r)$ equals $P(|X -\mu|^2\geqslant r^2)$.

Every proof I've looked up seems to state it as an obvious "fact" but I just don't get why, or rather, I don't understand how to "picture" what the probability of a squared r.v looks like.

Why is it that the squared probability of an event equals the probability of that same event?

Comment: You're way overthinking this. :)

Comment: @ZacharySelk Yup, you are right, I only realized how easy my question was after posting it lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the squared probability of the event. The event $$|x-\mu|\ge r$$ is the *same event* as $$|x-\mu|^2\ge r^2$$
This is because you are squaring two positive quantities. So, the probability of two identical events is identical.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is exactly the same event. Suppose that $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is a probability space and let us recall that a random variable is a measurable map $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. We have that
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega:|X(\omega)-\mu|\ge r\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:|X(\omega)-\mu|^2\ge r^2\}
$$
since $|X(\omega)-\mu|\ge r$ if and only if $|X(\omega)-\mu|^2\ge r^2$. Hence, the probabilities of these events are the same
$$
P(|X(\omega)-\mu|\ge r)=P(|X(\omega)-\mu|^2\ge r^2).
$$